# prevent a notification from making sound

Tags: java, android

I want to make a notification that just shows the status of something in the notification panel without vibration or sound.  I tried setting the sound and vibration to null but it just does the default one.  How would I do this?

Comment: Please post your code where you are configuring the `Notification`.

Comment: Sorry I realized my issue.  I was the notification to default a bit below